# Неработает код (предположительно условный оператор), выводит обычные include'ы

Tags: php, include, if

```
//Содержимое index.php
<?php
include('./header.html');
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
echo $lang;
if ($lang == 'ru') {include('./ru.php');} else {echo 'not ru';};
if ($lang == 'en') { include('./en.php');} else {echo 'not en';};
echo $langa;
include('./footer.html');
?>

//содержимое ru.php
<?php
$langa = 'Russian';
?>

//содержимое en.php
<?php
$langa = 'English';
?>
```

Выводит содержимое header.html и footer.html, а между ними ничего. Если просто include('./ru.php'), то работает, но мне нужно в завистмости от условия. Даже echo $lang нерабтает, а если убрать условные операторы, то выводит нормально.

Comment: @n.osennij зачем ../ru.php, если всё в одной директории?

Comment: @n.osennij что бы дать понять php что ru.php и en.php лежат в одной директории.

Comment: Всё, почти разобрался. Закоментировал строку со вторым условным оператором.
Только еще несовсем понял, как это влияет.

Comment: в порядке комментария: `if(in_array($lang, ['ru', 'en'])){ include "./{$lang}.php"; }` (либо `||`)

Comment: $langa - это кто? Вроде переменная называется $lang...

Comment: @labris $lang это переменная содержащая выхлоп substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2); (выхлоп вида: en или ru ). А $langa это переменная, которая берётся из ru.php или en.php (в зависимости от условия). Хочу обратить Ваше внимание, на то что тут две переменные: $lang и $langa.